# Calendar popup of Richfaces or Primefaces not working

Tags: jsf-2, calendar, richfaces

I have added richfaces 4.3.0 jars in my project and also tried with primefaces3.4.2 in netbeans 7.2.1

I am trying to use calendar component in my project but when I am using richfaces or primefaces calendar popup doesn't appear and it remains and it is or its not giving any error

I have used the following code in my .xhtml file

```
<rich:calendar  id="givenDate" enableManualInput="true" style="width:60px" datePattern="MM/dd/yyyy" value="#{NewClass.ts}" immediate = "true"  required="true" popup="true" />
```

In the java bean I have used the variable of java.util.Date type with getter and setter method.
Can Anybody please point me what I am doing wrong.

Solved:-
I forgot to add h:head tag in xhtml page thats why neither richfaces not primefaces was working.

Comment: Do you have to mix richfaces and primefaces? First remove one of them, test your code to understand if it originates from using two component libs. together

Comment: No do not want to use both together first I tried with primefaces calendar it didn't work so I decided to move to richfaces but it is also not showing popup calendar...

Comment: Yipppi I solved the problem. Actually I forgot to add h:head in my xhtml page...

Answer (score 0):

Primefaces calendar width change size tag

```
<p:calendar size="7" />
```